# Self-adjoint functionals

Tags: quantum-field-theory

Usually, QFT is used in operator representation, that is one can write e.g. $-i\partial_{t}\psi=H\psi$ with H being an operator. And one can ask if H is self-adjoint etc.
However, there's also the possibility of the functional representation where H would be a functional. What would be the analog of self-adjointness for functonals?

THX

Comment: Comment to question (v1): The word _functional_ means different things in different branches of mathematical physics. You might receive better and more focused answers by providing some context (e.g., references, examples, etc.) for your question.